# C# Script Block Register

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Any one can help me because i'm Trying to register a script first and bind a function called "DoClick()" into button using C# but some error is occurred during runtime. please see my code below. so that when button was click they call the function "DoClick(). Thanks Guys

```
public void regiterAdsScript(int loc)
{
    string adsLink = ads_link(loc);       
    // Define the name and type of the client script on the page.
    String csName = "ButtonClickScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();
    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    // Check to see if the client script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
    {
        StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
        csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> \n");
        csText.Append("function DoClick() { <script type='text/javascript' src='//abcd.site?id=123'></script> }  \n");
        csText.Append("</script>");
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return DoClick()");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error you see at runtime!

Comment: I am not sure if `function DoClick() { <script type='text/javascript' src='//abcd.site?id=123'></script> }` is valid. It's a script in a script block.

Comment: what is this src='//abcd.site?id=123'.? it supposed to be `.js`

Comment: Your `DoClick` function body is definitely invalid. Either place valid JavaScript code inside, or remove the whole function and simply include the script from `abcd.site`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script registration code should be like this

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:DoClick();");
```

Also, your script looks wrong. Whatever you want your script to do should be followed by function declaration. Like if you want to put an alert it should be like this

```
csText.Append("function DoClick() { alert('MK'); }  \n");
```

You also need to call the function *regiterAdsScript()* before the Button1_Click is called. I've called it in the Page_load itself. Below is sample program for you:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    regiterAdsScript();  
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //functionality to be implemented
}
public void regiterAdsScript()
{
    string adsLink = ads_link(loc);
    // Define the name and type of the client script on the page.
    String csName = "ButtonClickScript";
    Type csType = this.GetType();
    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    // Check to see if the client script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
    {
        StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
        csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> \n");
        csText.Append("function DoClick() { alert('MK'); }  \n");
        csText.Append("</script>");
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:DoClick();");
    }
}
```